# Compare date columns

Tags: teradata

I need to retrieve the rows that service_date is greater than prod_date.
The data type for prod_date is VARCHAR(10) (2/20/2014 for example) and the data type for service_date is DATE (YYYYMMDD). If I query service_date using "select service_date from service where service_date ='20140201'", the result is showing "2/1/2014" in the result grid. However, it does not work in the query below when I convert service_date to varchar to compare with prod_date.  It pulls out all the rows instead of the ones that have greater service_date.

```
SELECT P.PROD_ID, P.PROD_DESC, S.PROD_ID, S.SERVICE_LOC
FROM PRODUCT P
INNER JOIN SERVICE S
WHERE P.PROD_ID = S.PROD_ID
AND CAST(S.SERVICE_DATE AS VARCHAR(10)) >= P.PROD_DATE
```

Comment: Are all the months between January and September single digit months for `PROD_DATE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use date ordering instead of string/varchar ordering if possible for simplicity and since its [ probably ] closer to what your interested in and less likely to confuse

For example

```
'01/02/2014' >= '04/01/2013'  -- if these are dates or cast to dates
```

but

```
'01/02/2014' <  '04/01/2013'  -- if these are strings
```

So to keep things simple, it makes sense to cast `PROD_DATE` to a date when comparing these two fields like :

```
SELECT P.PROD_ID, P.PROD_DESC, S.PROD_ID, S.SERVICE_LOC
FROM PRODUCT P
INNER JOIN SERVICE S
WHERE P.PROD_ID = S.PROD_ID
AND S.SERVICE_DATE >= cast(P.PROD_DATE as date format 'DD/MM/YYYY')
;
```

if theres any doubts on prod_dates quality as valid dates can check the conversion on all dates first ( before running/adjusting above )

Comment: It gives me "invalid date" error when I cast PROD_DATE to date format.

Comment: The format is invalid because Teradata expects a two digit month. I cannot see a way to force the FORMAT clause to accept a single digit month.

Comment: Correct.  I just did a test and teradata only accepts two digit format.

Comment: I changed the date format in the excel to two digits date format so either cast prod_date to date format works or cast the service_date to date and then varchar(10) format works also.  Thanks for sharing the knowledge so I realized I need to work around to change the date format in excel for the volatile product table.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't 100% error proof given your date is character and could have unexpected values. It does show how you can append a leading 0 to the month value and cast it to a date when the month is determined to be a single digit based on the location of the `/` in the second position of the `PROD_DATE` value for a given row.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN POSITION('/' IN TRIM(P.PROD_DATE)) = 2
            THEN CAST('0'|| TRIM(P.PROD_DATE) AS CHAR(10)) AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY')
            ELSE CAST(P.PROD_DATE AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY')
       END AS PROD_DATE_
  FROM PRODUCT P;
```